# Maximization problem on finite collection of finite sets

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, optimization, combinatorics

### Problem

I am considering the following maximization problem:

- **Input** is a finite collection of finite sets $\mathcal{F} = \{ X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n \}$.
- **Goal** is to find a subset $G \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ that maximizes $|G| \times |\bigcap G|$ where

  - $|G|$ is the cardinality of the set $G$, and
  - $\bigcap G = \bigcap \{X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_m} \} = X_{i_1} \cap X_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap X_{i_m}$.

As an example, for the collection
$$
\mathcal{F} = \{ \{a, b, c\}, \{a, b, c, x\}, \{b, c, y\}, \{a, b, c, z\} \},
$$
the maximizing subset is $G = \{ \{a, b, c\}, \{a, b, c, x\}, \{a, b, c, z\} \}$
and the score is $3 \times |\{a, b, c\}| = 9$.

Note: the score of $\mathcal{F}$ itself is $4 \times |\{b, c\}| = 8$.

### Question

I am planning to use a procedure of this problem for compressing data (represented by finite collections of finite sets).
However, I don't have any good idea to solve this problem efficiently.
As yow know, we can solve this by enumerating all the collections of $\mathcal{F}$; but, it's too slow for practical use.

Is there a polynomial-time or some kind of efficient algorithm for this problem?
Or, does this problem belong to the complexity class that cannot be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: I think I understand why $\bigcap G = \bigcap \{X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \ldots, X_{i_m} \} = X_{i_1} \cap X_{i_2} \cap \cdots \cap X_{i_m}$ is of advantage (there may be one $ \cap G$ missing in both explications). I fail to see the value of maximising $|G|$, let alone multiplying that to the former: please provide the intuition for that goal.

Comment: @greybeard Thank you for your interesting. I try to answer your questions.

1. Is maximizing | \bigcap G | useful ?

This problem equals to find one of the largest set $X_i$ from $\mathcal{F}$ and it can be solved in linear time.

BTW, I've found [this pdf](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~eduardo/publications/ipl12.pdf) about "Maximum k-Subset Intersection" (MSI) problem.
On this, for a given $k$, we find a collection $H \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ with $|H| = k$ that maximizes $| \bigcap H |$.
This is also interesting!!
The paper shows MSI and Maximum-edge biclique problem are closely related.

Comment: 2. How do we use this problem?

Let me explain my original motivation, compactifying finite collections of finite sets, by reusing the above instance.
On the example, the collection $\mathcal{F}$ can be rephrased as follows by
using $\bigcap G = \{ a, b, c \}$:

$$
\mathcal{F} \approx \langle \mathcal{G} = \{a, b, c\} \&\& \{ \mathcal{G}, \mathcal{G} \cup x, \{ b, c, y \},  \mathcal{G} \cup z \} \rangle.
$$

Using $\bigcap G$, we can obtain the shorter representation.
To this end, I need the above problem rather than MSI.
I hope these will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is NP-complete. Let's reformulate it first: we have a bipartite graph, where

- The left side corresponds to elements
- The right side corresponds to sets
- The edge $(u,v)$ means that $u \in v$.

Our goal is to find the bipartite clique with the maximum number of edges. As stated in [Rene Peeters, "The maximum edge biclique problem is NP-complete"](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/%7Evassilis/co/biclique.pdf), the decision problem is NP-complete.

Comment: Thanks so much for your great answer! I'd have explored a useful variant of the (biparate) maximum matching, but I couldn't.

Your answer, "the maximum edge biclique problem", quite naturally encodes my problem.
Reading the mentioned and [some related papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03581), I've also understood to develop an approximating algorithm may be hard.